# Resetting , unmounting screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I used to work with react navigation 2.6.2 and everything was fine , but with react navigation 3.xx I faced the problem where the screen's state is never unmounted while switch between them. I was surfing solutions and finally I'm here.

Ive already looked up Stack Actions in docs, but they gave just a slice of code from what I didn't understand where to apply it, please help me.

Comment: What is your use case for needing to reset the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are correct, with 3.x.x the way navigation works has changed. Moving from one screen to another does not actually unmount the previous one. This is because with 3.x.x the navigation stack uses the native behaviour which preserves the state of the previous screen when pushing a route.

React navigation instead fires events for willBlur, willFocus, didBlur and didFocus which can be used to detect when a user enters and exits a screen. You can take a look at the API spec for more details on the react navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle)